# Unable to use pip package obtained from building Tensorflow 2.3 from source

Tags: tensorflow, cuda

I've managed to build Tensorflow 2.3 from source, following these instructions:
https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-compile-tensorflow-2-3-with-cuda-11-1-8cbecffcb8d3

But, when I install obtained pip package in new conda environment, and import tensorflow, I get following error: `Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.11.1'; dlerror: libcudart.so.11.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I've managed to use GPU support with CUDA 11.1 for Tensorflow 2.5 nightly, without creating soft links between libs (I get `Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.11.0` message).

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's working with symbolic link:
libcudart.so.11.1 -> libcudart.so.11.0

I guess it's because the nightly build has CUDA 11.1 fully supported.